# Download HTML file using a tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to download a HTML file using an `a` tag following is my code. 
It is working in Chrome and Firefox but it does not works in IE

```
 var a = document.createElement("a");
 a.href = "data:text/html,"+htmlContent;
 a.target      = '_blank';
 a.download = "test.html";
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.click();
```

Any ideas what might causing the issue

Comment: "Does not work" is not really an explanation of what issue you are facing. In addition, including the IE version would be very helpful. For all we know you are talking about IE 6 :P

Comment: Please include in your post exactly what problem you are facing - are there any errors? Unexpected behaviors?

Comment: Try using `alert()` or `console.log()` to try to narrow down what is going wrong

Comment: "Dose not work" in the sense it does nothing when i called this code through function but in Chrome and Firefox it will download the file. 

And I am using IE 11

Answer (score 4):

`download` attribute of `<a>` element is not supported on ie. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Here is a great resource with "up-to-date browser support tables for support of front-end web technologies on desktop and mobile web browsers" - http://caniuse.com/#search=download

Answer (score 1):

As the `download` attribute is only a relatively recent addition to HTML5, it's not wise to expect widespread support from browsers just yet.

Currently, the only reliable way to ensure a browser initiates a download when opening a URL is to have the server send the correct headers telling it to do so:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.html`

As the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility) will tell you, the attribute is completely unsupported by all versions of IE, meaning it's still a bit too early to rely on the `download` attribute. I'd recommend server intervention for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Switch you href to include the actual file name, and then add a

```
?forcedownload=1
```

to the end of it. This should work for IE.